# Cocoa-Touch, NSManagedObject: Exception when setting a property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a NSManagedObject subclass, created by the XCode model interface.
This class has some NSString and NSNumber members, and a NSDate member.

When I try to set the NSDate member, I get the following exception:
`2009-10-12 21:53:32.228 xxx[2435:20b] Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Item'

2009-10-12 21:53:32.228 xxx[2435:20b] *** -[Item setDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3f7ed30

2009-10-12 21:53:32.229 xxx[2435:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[Item setDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3f7ed30'`

The date parameter is just like the others, except that instead of being a

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NS{String,Number}* propname;
```

it's a

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date;
```

Btw, the `Item` instance I'm assigning on is just a regular `[[Item alloc] init]`, no associated context or anything.

First I thought my NSDate* was faulty, then I tried assigning it [NSDate date], and even nil. It still crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: What means this notation "NS{String,Number}" ?

Comment: @ValeryPavlov it's from bash, it expands to NSString and NSNumber. Doesn't work in ObjC, it's just quicker to type that way. E.g. Example{1,2,3} expands to Example1, Example2, Example3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't instantiate an `NSManagedObject` subclass without an associated `NSManagedObjectContext` (well you *can* as you've shown, but the results will almost certainly not be what you want).

The first line of the log hints at this:

```
2009-10-12 21:53:32.228 xxx[2435:20b] Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Item'
```

All Objective-C classes have (by convention) a *designated initializer*, which is the initializer method that *must* be called, either explicitly or via an other convenience initializer. In the case of `NSManagedObject` this is `-[NSManagedObject initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:]`. Failure to cause the designated initializer leads to undefined, and likely incorrect, behavior because the instance is not guaranteed to be properly initialized. I would guess that the `NSManagedObject` initializer sets up the machinery to support `@synthesize`'d property access for the Entity's attributes. Without this machinery, the instance may not think it can respond to the `@synthesize`'d calls and your call to `setData:` will cause a selector not found error.

Comment: oh, I'll try adding the context too then. Pretty weird since only this property fails.

Comment: I suspect the inconsistency in failure with other properties is a bit of luck.