# Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'ClassName'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am using mogenerator.I am getting CoreData error as follows:

> Failed to call designated initializer
>   on NSManagedObject class 'ClassName'.

Anybody please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556304/cocoa-touch-nsmanagedobject-exception-when-setting-a-property?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't alloc / initalise something that you already have a hand on.. that's why !

Example of use in a cellForRowAtIndexPath

Use
`ClassName *class = [arrayOfSomething objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Instead of
`ClassName *class = [ClassName alloc] init];
class = [arrayOfSomething objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 2):

You need to show the associated code before anyone can assist.  Otherwise we are just guessing.

Show how you are initializing `ClassName`.

Comment: Thanks.Previous time i was using ClassName *dataObj = [[ClassName alloc] init]; dataObj = ....retrival code.... . Now   am using ClassName *dataObj =  ..retrival code..    When i removed [[ClassName alloc] init],all worked.

Answer (score 2):

Do not alloc init your Bean class, instead use following method to set Bean:

```
-(void)setBean:(YourBeanClassName *)obj
{
    objBean = obj;
}
```